# convert seconds as double to std::chrono::duration?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

I'm using c++11 `<chrono>` and have a number of seconds represented as a double. I want to use c++11 to sleep for this duration, but I cannot fathom how to convert it to a `std::chrono::duration` object that `std::this_thread::sleep_for` requires.

```
const double timeToSleep = GetTimeToSleep();
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(timeToSleep));  // cannot convert from double to seconds
```

I've locked at the `<chrono>` reference but I find it rather confusing.

Thanks

EDIT:

The following gives error:

```
std::chrono::duration<double> duration(timeToSleep );
std::this_thread::sleep_for(duration);
```

the error:

```
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\chrono(749): error C2679: binary '+=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const std::chrono::duration<double,std::ratio<0x01,0x01>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
2>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\chrono(166): could be 'std::chrono::duration<__int64,std::nano> &std::chrono::duration<__int64,std::nano>::operator +=(const std::chrono::duration<__int64,std::nano> &)'
2>          while trying to match the argument list '(std::chrono::nanoseconds, const std::chrono::duration<double,std::ratio<0x01,0x01>>)'
2>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\thread(164) : see reference to function template instantiation 'xtime std::_To_xtime<double,std::ratio<0x01,0x01>>(const std::chrono::duration<double,std::ratio<0x01,0x01>> &)' being compiled
2>          c:\users\johan\desktop\svn\jonsengine\jonsengine\src\window\glfw\glfwwindow.cpp(73) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::this_thread::sleep_for<double,std::ratio<0x01,0x01>>(const std::chrono::duration<double,std::ratio<0x01,0x01>> &)' being compiled
```

Comment: Cornstalks' answer is correct.  This looks like a bug in VS11 `std::this_thread::sleep_for`.  You could try `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono:duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(duration))` to work around the bug.  I chose milliseconds arbitrarily.  Use whatever works, but let `<chrono>` supply  the conversions instead of rolling your own.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Don't do `std::chrono::seconds(timeToSleep)`. You want something more like:

```
std::chrono::duration<double>(timeToSleep)
```

Alternatively, if `timeToSleep` is not measured in seconds, you can pass a ratio as a template parameter to `duration`. See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) (and the examples there) for more information.

Answer (score 6):

Making the answer from @Cornstalks a little more generic, you could define a function like this:

```
template <typename T>
auto seconds_to_duration(T seconds) {
    return std::chrono::duration<T, std::ratio<1>>(seconds);
}
```

This will convert a seconds value of any primitive type to a chrono duration. Use it like this:

```
const double timeToSleep = GetTimeToSleep();
std::this_thread_sleep_for(seconds_to_duration(timeToSleep));
```

Answer (score 5):

None of the above worked for me. The working solution was found as an answer to a different question:

[Terse conversion from double seconds to std::chrono::steady_clock::duration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45884081/terse-conversion-from-double-seconds-to-stdchronosteady-clockduration)

```
double period_in_seconds = 3.4;

auto as_duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::steady_clock::duration>(std::chrono::duration<double>(period_in_seconds));
```

This converts a `double` to a `std::chrono::steady_clock::duration`.

In general, when working with a standard clock, such as `steady_clock`, your duration variables should always be of that clock's member type, such as `std::chrono::steady_clock::duration`.

Avoid creating your own duration types from the template, such as `std::chrono::duration<double>`, except for temporary use with `duration_cast` as shown above.

This makes time comparisons against `std::chrono::steady_clock::now()` fastest, as it avoids needless conversion at runtime, as the duration type of your variables will already match the duration type of the `time_point` returned by `now()`.

Answer (score 4):

```
const unsigned long timeToSleep = static_cast<unsigned long>( GetTimeToSleep() * 1000 );
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(timeToSleep));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `*operator` overload to convert the double to a `std::chrono::duration<double>` and then cast it to you desired period.

```cpp
double start;
auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>
    ( 
        std::chrono::seconds{1} * start
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
std::chrono::milliseconds duration(timeToSleep);
std::this_thread::sleep_for( duration );
```

Comment: There is no chrono::milliseconds constructor that accepts double.