# Terse conversion from double seconds to std::chrono::steady_clock::duration?

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I can do this:

```
double period_in_seconds = 3.4;

auto as_duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::steady_clock::duration>(std::chrono::duration<double>(period_in_seconds));
```

But I'm sure you'll agree that is quite ridiculous. Is there a terser way?

*Edit:* Beside the obvious `using namespace std::chrono`.

Comment: `std::chrono::seconds`?

Comment: Write a function?

Comment: Maybe the `using namespace std::chrono;` in local scope or using other aliases?

Comment: `std::chrono::seconds` only measures an integer number of seconds as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2):

There is good reason to be fanatic about discouraging use of `using namespace`s at file scope, especially in headers.  However at *function scope,* especially with the `<chrono>` lib, `using namespace std::chrono` is your friend.

Just this step gets you from:

```
double period_in_seconds = 3.4;
auto as_duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::steady_clock::duration>(std::chrono::duration<double>(period_in_seconds));
```

to:

```
double period_in_seconds = 3.4;
using namespace std::chrono;
auto as_duration = duration_cast<steady_clock::duration>(duration<double>(period_in_seconds));
```

I recommend the use of `round` when casting from a floating point duration to an integral duration.  Not only will this give the "expected" answer more often, but it is slightly less verbose than `duration_cast`.  `std::chrono::round` is new with C++17.  But you can grab it from various places like [here](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/date.h#L1056-L1078) or [here](http://howardhinnant.github.io/duration_io/chrono_util.html) and start using it today. Also if you use `{}` for constructors it helps distinguish object construction from function calls, making the code a little easier to read:

```
double period_in_seconds = 3.4;
using namespace std::chrono;
auto as_duration = round<steady_clock::duration>(duration<double>{period_in_seconds});
```

Finally, don't hesitate to create a custom duration, even if in a local scope to improve readability:

```
double period_in_seconds = 3.4;
using namespace std::chrono;
using dsec = duration<double>;
auto as_duration = round<steady_clock::duration>(dsec{period_in_seconds});
```

*Edit:* And if for some reason (say a misplaced style guide) you can't using a function-local `using namespace std::chrono`, then you can make up for that with more specific type aliases and using declarations:

```
double period_in_seconds = 3.4;
using dsec = std::chrono::duration<double>;
using duration = std::chrono::steady_clock::duration;
using std::chrono::round;
auto as_duration = round<duration>(dsec{period_in_seconds});
```

If this code is intended to be at file scope and you don't want these usings at file scope (which is perfectly understandable), just create a function to encapsulate them:

```
constexpr
std::chrono::steady_clock::duration
get_period(double period_in_seconds)
{
    using dsec = std::chrono::duration<double>;
    using duration = std::chrono::steady_clock::duration;
    using std::chrono::round;
    return round<duration>(dsec{period_in_seconds});
}

auto constexpr as_duration = get_period(3.4);
```

Above I've even demonstrated that this particular example can all be done at compile time.  `clang -O3 -S` reduces the above down to the following assembly:

```
    .globl  _as_duration            ## @as_duration
    .p2align    3
_as_duration:
    .quad   3400000000              ## 0xcaa7e200
```