# How to convert std::chrono::duration to double (seconds)?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

Let's have `using duration = std::chrono::steady_clock::duration`. I would like to convert duration to double in seconds with maximal precision elegantly.

I have found [the reverse way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17899684/convert-seconds-as-double-to-stdchronoduration), but it didn't help me finding it out.

Alternatively expressed, I want optimally some std function `double F(duration)`, which returns seconds.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Simply do:

```
std::chrono::duration<double>(d).count()
```

Or, as a function:

```
template <class Rep, class Period>
constexpr auto F(const std::chrono::duration<Rep,Period>& d)
{
    return std::chrono::duration<double>(d).count();
}
```

If you need more complex casts that cannot be fulfilled by the [`std::chrono::duration` constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration), use [`std::chrono::duration_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration_cast).

Comment: How do we get it in seconds without specifying `std::chrono::seconds`?

Comment: @nj2237 the default `std::ratio` for `std::chrono::duration` is `1`, which means seconds. You could say `std::chrono::duration<double,std::ratio<1,1000>>` to get a millisecond duration, `duration<double,ratio<1000,1>>` to get kiloseconds, etc.

Answer (score 9):

Converting a `std::chrono::duration` to any numeric "count" is deceptively simple!

You can **divide** any two `std::chrono::duration`s to efficiently
get a count.

Given a duration `d` of any period and any integer representation:

```
using std::chrono_literals;

// Want to know how many seconds?  Divide by one second!
std::int64_t int_seconds = d / 1s;
double       fp_seconds  = d / 1.0s;
```

As shown, it does not matter what the period is of the two durations.  And the resulting type will be the [common type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type) of the two durations.

Answer (score 5):

This is the most straightforward way for me:

```cpp
auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

/*code*/

auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
std::chrono::duration<double> diff = end - start;
std::cout << "Duration [seconds]: " << diff.count() << std::endl;
```

however I do not know about precision... Although this method is pretty precise.

Comment: How does this know to be seconds?

Comment: "Represents the length of a period in seconds." - https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/steady_clock/ . I believe that the default `period` is seconds in `std::chrono::steady_clock` and that is the reason `count()` returns seconds. "The representation value of the object as a count of periods." - https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/duration/count/

Comment: Use std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> diff = end - start  to get diff value in milliseconds. Similarly std::micro or std::nano can be used.