# c++: convert std::chrono of variable unit to seconds

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

Let's say I have a `timeInterval` parameter that's a `std::chrono::duration`, but of a non-predetermined unit size - sometimes it'll be `std::chrono::seconds`, sometimes `std::chrono:milliseconds`, who knows.

Let's say I have a `float DamagePerSecond` - to calculate the damage done over the time interval, I need to calculate the floating point value of the `timeInterval` in seconds, and just multiply them.

From a lot of Googling, viewing tutorials on YouTube, and viewing solutions on here, it seems that `.count()` gives whole number of seconds.

Ultimately, I just want to find:

```cpp
float totalDamage = DamagePerSecond * timeIntervalInSeconds;
```

This seems really frustratingly hard, and it's baffling that I haven't yet seen this covered after a good hour of looking through YouTube/Googling.

```cpp
auto testX = std::chrono::milliseconds(5);
auto duration_s = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(testX);
Log(L"%f\n" duration_s.count());  // This just prints out 0.00000, probably because type mismatch
Log(L"%i\n" duration_s.count());  // This just prints out 0, because there's not a whole number second yet
```

I tried to follow the solution here:

[How to convert std::chrono::duration to double (seconds)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57538507/)

```cpp
auto testX = std::chrono::milliseconds(5);
float converted = std::chrono:duration<double>(testX).count();
Log(L"%f\n", converted);
```

But this yields the following errors:

```
error C2882: 'chrono': illegal use of namespace identifier in expression
error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before ':'
error C2059: syntax error: ':'
```

Comment: `chrono:duration` ???

Comment: In hindsight, this question is about a typo.  `std::chrono::duration` was accidentally transcribed as `std::chrono:duration` and that's what the error is indicating.

Answer (score 9):

You may divide any two `std::chrono::duration`s of any type or period to efficiently get a count in the common type.

```
template <class Rep, class Period>
constexpr double seconds(std::chrono::duration<Rep,Period> d)
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;

    // How many seconds?  Divide by one second!
    // The units cancel out and you get a number.
    return d / 1.0s;
}
```

Note that this technique can also give you a "count" of any unusual duration.

- How many 2 minute intervals?
- How many 33 nanosecond intervals?

Just divide by that amount.

Comment: That's neat to, never thought of doing it like that before. But works like a charm : https://onlinegdb.com/mEEctuI3Y. At least a little thanks from my end.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I didn't know for the longest time either, but it's rather easy to read.  Arguably moreso than with all the casts and count()s

Comment: I am charmed by it, because it is a good abstraction and clearly shows intent. Which indeed gets lost in all the casts otherwise. (I so love learning even after 30 years of C++ it can still positively surprise you)

Comment: Not sure, if you need to pass durations by const reference. I expect them effectively be passed by value with the same efficiency as `Rep`...

Comment: @fabian I would normally pass them by value as well (they are the size of the underlying type).  I was merely lifting from the linked Q/A.  Yes, pass them by value!

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there, the syntax is this :

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

int main()
{
    auto duration = 125ms;

    // duration cast gives the number of counts in the unit you asked for.
    auto milliseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(duration).count();

    // convert milliseconds to seconds by dividing by 1000
    auto seconds = static_cast<double>(milliseconds) / 1000.0;

    std::cout << seconds << "s";

    return 0;
}
```

Live demo : https://onlinegdb.com/r7G3QpZzT

Comment: Why convert in two steps rather than just `std::chrono::duration_cast` directly to floating point seconds?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Funnily enough I didn't know std::chrono as well as I did see replies to Drew Dorman. I learned some things today :)  One is that I didn't know floating point was a thing in std::chrono.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply `duration_cast` to `std::chrono::duration<double>`:

```
template<class Duration>
constexpr double Damage(Duration d)
{
    using FloatSecond = std::chrono::duration<double>;

    constexpr double Dps = 1234.567;

    return Dps * std::chrono::duration_cast<FloatSecond>(d).count();
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;

    std::cout
        << Damage(1ms) << '\n'
        << Damage(5s) << '\n'
        << Damage(1min) << '\n';
}
```